# Create arrays with number in ascending order

Tags: reactjs

```
 let i=0;
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState([]);
  for (i;i<6;i++){
    setInputs([...Inputs, i]);
  }
```

`inputs = [1,2,3,4,5];  //expected òutput`

i know this is wrong in react, but how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write your logic inside `useEffect` as I have passed dependency array as empty so it will run only once.

```
const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
      arr.push(i);
    }
    setNumbers(arr);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
        return () =>{
            for (let i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
                setNumbers(prevState => [...prevState, i])
            }
        }
    }, []);
```

Comment: This isn’t an optimised solution as every time you are re-rendering the component .